# Road Distance calculation in mysql

Tags: mysql

Am trying to fetch the stations along with the road distance from the origin(hyderabad coordinates- 17.3850,78.4867). With the below query am getting the distance but it is aerial distance. I require road side distance.

my sql:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude,Station_Name, Station_Key,
(6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(
            POWER(SIN((17.3850 - ABS(latitude)) * PI()/180 / 2),
            2) + COS(17.3850 * PI()/180 ) * COS(ABS(latitude) *
            PI()/180) * POWER(SIN((78.4867 - longitude) *
            PI()/180 / 2), 2) ))) AS distnce
FROM abrs_stations
```

so can any one pls let me know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the Google Maps API (or other competing APIs).

Comment: How can you get road side distance from latitude-longitude coordinates?

Comment: @Manav : If i know how to get that, then i will write answer for this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google API for find distance between two lat long

> ```
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" . $from_latitude . "," . $from_longitude . "&destinations=" . $destination_latitude . "," . $destination_longitude . "&mode=driving&language=pl-PL
> ```

using this url you get response from where you can get your distance.

```
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" . $from_latitude . "," . $from_longitude . "&destinations=" . $destination_latitude . "," . $destination_longitude . "&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);

  $distance=  $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
```

here `$distance` is your distance between two lat long by `google API`

Answer (score 1):

Aerial distance is the only thing you can calculate with the data you have. If you only need to know the road distance from Hyderabad (and not the exact path), then you find out the road distance for each location in your database (e.g. using Google Maps) and store it in your database. If you want to determine the road distance dynamically, then you have to look for an API (maybe Google Maps API) that gives you road distance between two co-ordinates.

Either way, **NO** you cannot do it purely in SQL.